# Xcode 15 Beta 8: WidgetKit #Preview Macro stopped working:

Tags: xcode, watchos, widgetkit, xcode15, swift-macro

Did something change as far as how to use #Preview macros in Xcode 15 Beta 8? This code used to work fine but now no longer compiles because of `== PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR: CompileDylibError: Failed to build WatchRecoveryWidget.swift  Compiling failed: cannot convert value of type 'WatchRecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry' to closure result type 'any View'`

```
  #Preview(as: WidgetFamily.accessoryRectangular) {
    WatchRecoveryScoreWidget()
} timeline: {
    WatchRecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry(date: Date(), recoveryScore: 75, subscriptionIsActive: true)
}
```

Comment: I filed a Feedback #13110291

Comment: Any update on the feedback you filed? I've had the same issue on RC and it is so frustrating!

Comment: I know there has been some talk about the Xcode release notes mentioning this as a known issue: "Previews can fail when previewing files in a widget shared by both a watchOS app and an iOS app. (108017929)"

But I have downloaded down to beta 6 and am still having this exact same issue about it trying to use my TimelineProvider (or TimelineEntry) as `any View`. Do you know what beta version you last used where it worked?

Comment: I still have the issue in the RC Xcode, I can only preview Widgets using the old `PreviewProvider ` API.  My widgets do use some code on the back end that is shared with the iOS app.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to address this issue by adding `@available(iOS 17.0, *)` above each my of previews. Not sure why the error it shows is so misleading, but hopefully that gets addressed in a future Xcode 15 update.

So your preview would look like this now:

```
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
#Preview(as: .accessoryRectangular) {
    WatchRecoveryScoreWidget()
} timeline: {
    WatchRecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry(date: .now, recoveryScore: 75, subscriptionIsActive: true)
}
```

Comment: Good idea but this didn't work for me, I am still seeing `Compiling failed: cannot convert value of type 'WatchRecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry' to closure result type 'any View'`

Comment: Do you just have a single preview macro? Do you have them in any other files without `@available(iOS 17.0, *)` above them? You have to put that above each preview macro.

Comment: Every preview Macro in the entire app or just 1 target? I have about 10 Widgets on the watch and have put @available(iOS 17.0, *) above it for each of them and have the same issue.  I didn't try in my iPhone Widget code but its a separate target so that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: Ahhh if they're shared between watchOS and iOS, then previews might be broken regardless. In the [release notes for Xcode 15](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes#Known-Issues) it mentions a known issue that "Previews can fail when previewing files in a widget shared by both a watchOS app and an iOS app. (108017929)"

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I have a ton of code shared between iOS and watchOS.

Comment: This fixed the very same issue for me. Pretty upsetting that stuff like this happens every major release. Whack padding, container background, previews. I just wanted to add new stuff.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well (iOS only code, no watchOS target)